# How do I create pointer to a function in Vala?

Tags: function-pointers, vala

I want to try Vala compiled as an object file with the -c option and link it statically with a program written in another language that also compiles to C. For that I need to use a callback that calls code written in another language. In c example I could do the following. How do I do it in Vala?

```
int myMult(int x, int y, int (* myCallback)(int)) {
    int res = x * y;
    printf("%d\n", res);

    printf("callbacked %d\n", myCallback(res));

    return (res * 2);
}
```

Comment: well that's a delegate, `delegate int MyCallbackFunc (int res);`

Comment: @AlexB - thanks https://github.com/bigos/Pyrulis/commit/a52b87c5d61bc274023437fdb16ffa45ad98fd78